# How to shuffle and deal with constraints?

Tags: algorithms, random-generation, games

I'm playing a 4-player game of cards. My opponents are called A, B and C. At the beginning of the game, each player has been dealt a hand of cards out of a deck containing 4 suits of cards: Black, Red, Yellow, Green.

The game is ongoing. A few tricks have already been played, and during these tricks I've learned that:

- A and C don't have (or no longer have) Black;
- B doesn't have Red.

Each player has 3 remaining cards in hand, and I know that the 9 cards that they have among them are: Black 1, 2; Red 1, 2; Yellow 1, 2; Green 1, 2, 3.

I would like to sample the possible hands of A,B,C. How can I simulate the distribution of possible hands, knowing what I know?

I could use sample rejection where I deal the 9 remaining cards like normal and check whether players have cards in suits that they are not allowed and re-shuffle and re-deal, but I would like a way to do the shuffle and deal only once.

If one player is missing suits, the problem is easy: I can remove those cards from the deck, shuffle just what the player could have and deal that out to the player, then deal the remaining cards to the other players, but in the case that more than one player is missing suits, by the time I get to the last player, the remaining cards I have to deal to the player could have suits that the player is not allowed, forcing a reshuffle.

How can I shuffle and deal only once guaranteeing that each player will have a valid hand?

I would appreciate a general method that I could apply not just for the example above, but any knowledge of who cannot have which suit, and any number of remaining cards.

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean by "cannot have cards that are in zero to three suits"? Does that mean each player has at least four suits of cards?  What do you assume about numbers of suits, numbers of cards, numbers of players, cards held by players, and how the cards were dealt?  *All* these details affect the solution and some of them might influence how one develops an answer.

Comment: Each player may have only 1 suit of card, or 2 going up to 4 suits. In other words, the probability of having a card is either zero (if it's one of the suits they cannot have) or non-zero (equal chance for all other card types, except when taking into account other players, the probability of having a card may go up to 100%).

Comment: There are 4 suits and could be between 3 and 6 players. The number of cards held by players varies, but is known. The cards were dealt fairly with equal probability to all players at the beginning of the game, but as the game progresses and cards are played, it can be seen that a player no longer has a suit. What is the probability they have the other cards given that other players may not have that suit (or even a different set of suits)?

Comment: Doesn't that probability depend on the rules of the game and details of how the game progressed? It cannot be determined solely from the information you specify in your question.

Comment: The game is a variation of Rook, a trick taking game. Each player is dealt a number of cards. I am simulating games based upon the current state of the game as play progresses. When a player does not follow suit, I can know with certainty that they no longer have any cards with that suit in their hand, changing the probability of the cards in their hand. The probability is further modified by knowing other players have zero probabilities of certain cards in their hand. How can I compute the overall probability of each card and "deal" the cards according to those probabilities for simulations?

Comment: I have more detail over at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77823034/creating-a-constrained-dealing-algorithm but it was suggested that I describe the problem more succinctly.

Comment: Given the amount of comments and lack of response, I have taken the liberty of submitting an edit to add clarifications. If you don't like it, my apologies. You can rollback the edit, or edit even more.